# Jenkins admin access issue

Tags: jenkins

Facing issue related to adding new users in Jenkins as I am not able to see Manager user options. Jenkins is using ldap for authentication. I believe I don't have admin access to add new user and our old admin has left the team. Is there any way get all admin access from server itself ?

Comment: Can you access `config.xml` file  ?

Comment: Please, have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your question accordingly. You'll be rewarded!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when making changes to secure Jenkins. Whenever you make a mistake and get locked out you may end up having to disable the security in the config.xml. Look for the following line and set it to false. Ofcourse, make sure to make a backup before changing this as the whole security configuration will be erased after you restart Jenkins

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```